# Trying to test a DAO on a java hibernate application, and I'm getting a NullPointerAcception

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, maven

I'm making an application in Java using Hibernate, Maven, and JUnit for testing. I've had quite a few errors, and my latest one is a nullpointerexception that I'm not seeing any obvious fixes for. Please let me know if I accidentally left out any helpful information. The exception occurs when I try to test the getById method in the PcBuildDao class.

the exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at persistence.PcBuildDaoTest.getById(PcBuildDaoTest.java:24)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:389)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:115)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$6(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:167)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:40)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:163)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:110)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.lambda$execute$3(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:83)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SingleTestExecutor.executeSafely(SingleTestExecutor.java:66)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:77)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.lambda$null$2(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:92)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:183)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:177)
    at java.base/java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:133)
    at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:150)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:173)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:497)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.lambda$execute$3(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:92)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SingleTestExecutor.executeSafely(SingleTestExecutor.java:66)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:77)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.lambda$null$2(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:92)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:183)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:177)
    at java.base/java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:133)
    at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:150)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:173)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:497)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.lambda$execute$3(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:92)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SingleTestExecutor.executeSafely(SingleTestExecutor.java:66)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:77)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:51)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:43)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:170)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:154)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:90)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:57)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater$1.execute(IdeaTestRunner.java:38)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.TestsRepeater.repeat(TestsRepeater.java:11)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:35)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:235)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:54)
```

hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hardwareviewer</property>
        <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver</property>

        <property name="connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="connection.password">student</property>

        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">5</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">20</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">300</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">50</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">3000</property>

        <mapping class="entity.PcBuild" />
        <mapping class="entity.User" />
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="[url I can't post here]"
      xsi:schemaLocation="[here too]">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>edu.matc.entjava.hardwareviewer</groupId>
  <artifactId>hardwareviewer</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>hardwareviewer Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>https://maven.apache.org</url>
  <properties>
    <maven.compiler.release>11</maven.compiler.release>

    <javax.version>7.0</javax.version>
    <mysql-version>8.0.16</mysql-version>
    <jstl-version>1.2</jstl-version>
    <log4j-version>2.10.0</log4j-version>
    <jupiter-version>5.0.0</jupiter-version>
    <junit.version>4.12</junit.version>
    <junit-platform-runner-version>1.0.0</junit-platform-runner-version>
    <junit-vintage-version>4.12.0</junit-vintage-version>
    <hibernate-core-version>5.4.4.Final</hibernate-core-version>
    <hibernate-c3p0-version>5.4.4.Final</hibernate-c3p0-version>

    <javb-api.version>2.3.1</javb-api.version>

    <maven-compiler-plugin-version>3.8.1</maven-compiler-plugin-version>
    <maven-surefire-plugin-version>2.19</maven-surefire-plugin-version>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax</groupId>
      <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
      <version>${javax.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!--  https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java  -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>mysql</groupId>
      <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
      <version>${mysql-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>jstl</groupId>
      <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
      <version>${jstl-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
      <version>${log4j-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
      <version>${log4j-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
      <version>${jupiter-version}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>${junit.version}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit-platform-runner</artifactId>
      <version>${junit-platform-runner-version}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
      <version>${junit-vintage-version}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
      <version>${hibernate-core-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-c3p0 -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
      <version>${hibernate-c3p0-version}</version>
    </dependency>



    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.xml.bind/jaxb-api -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
      <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
      <version>${javb-api.version}</version>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <finalName>hardwareviewer</finalName>

    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>${maven-compiler-plugin-version}</version>
          <configuration>
            <source>1.8</source>
            <target>1.8</target>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.3</version>
          <configuration>
            <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
          <configuration>
            <webResources>
              <resource>
                <directory>src/main/webapp/META-INF</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
                <targetPath>META-INF</targetPath>
              </resource>
            </webResources>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>${maven-surefire-plugin-version}</version>
          <dependencies>
            <dependency>
              <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
              <artifactId>junit-platform-surefire-provider</artifactId>
              <version>${junit-platform-runner-version}</version>
            </dependency>
          </dependencies>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
</project>
```

PcBuild POJO

```
package entity;

import org.hibernate.annotations.GenericGenerator;
import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity(name = "PcBuild")
@Table(name = "computer_builds")
public class PcBuild {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "native")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "native", strategy = "native")
    private int buildId;

    @Column(name = "cpu_model")
    private String cpuModel;

    @Column(name = "gpu_model")
    private String gpuModel;

    @Column(name = "cpu_cooler_model")
    private String cpuCoolerModel;

    @Column(name = "Motherboard_model")
    private String motherboardModel;

    @Column(name = "psu_model")
    private String psuModel;

    @Column(name = "case_model")
    private String caseModel;

    @Column(name = "data_storage_model")
    private String dataStorageModel;

    @Column(name = "ram_model")
    private String ramModel;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "userId", referencedColumnName = "userId")
    private User user;

    public PcBuild() {
    }

    public PcBuild(int buildId, String cpuModel, String gpuModel,
            String cpuCoolerModel, String motherboardModel, String psuModel,
            String caseModel, String dataStorageModel, String ramModel,
            User user) {
        this.buildId = buildId;
        this.cpuModel = cpuModel;
        this.gpuModel = gpuModel;
        this.cpuCoolerModel = cpuCoolerModel;
        this.motherboardModel = motherboardModel;
        this.psuModel = psuModel;
        this.caseModel = caseModel;
        this.dataStorageModel = dataStorageModel;
        this.ramModel = ramModel;
        this.user = user;
    }

    public int getBuildId() {
        return buildId;
    }

    public void setBuildId(int buildId) {
        this.buildId = buildId;
    }

    public String getCpuModel() {
        return cpuModel;
    }

    public void setCpuModel(String cpuModel) {
        this.cpuModel = cpuModel;
    }

    public String getGpuModel() {
        return gpuModel;
    }

    public void setGpuModel(String gpuModel) {
        this.gpuModel = gpuModel;
    }

    public String getCpuCoolerModel() {
        return cpuCoolerModel;
    }

    public void setCpuCoolerModel(String cpuCoolerModel) {
        this.cpuCoolerModel = cpuCoolerModel;
    }

    public String getMotherboardModel() {
        return motherboardModel;
    }

    public void setMotherboardModel(String motherboardModel) {
        this.motherboardModel = motherboardModel;
    }

    public String getPsuModel() {
        return psuModel;
    }

    public void setPsuModel(String psuModel) {
        this.psuModel = psuModel;
    }

    public String getCase_Model() {
        return caseModel;
    }

    public void setCase_Model(String caseModel) {
        this.caseModel = caseModel;
    }

    public String getDataStorageModel() {
        return dataStorageModel;
    }

    public void setDataStorageModel(String dataStorageModel) {
        this.dataStorageModel = dataStorageModel;
    }

    public String getRamModel() {
        return ramModel;
    }

    public void setRamModel(String ramModel) {
        this.ramModel = ramModel;
    }

    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUserId(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "PcBuild{" +
                "buildId=" + buildId +
                ", cpuModel='" + cpuModel + '\'' +
                ", gpuModel='" + gpuModel + '\'' +
                ", cpuCoolerModel='" + cpuCoolerModel + '\'' +
                ", motherboardModel='" + motherboardModel + '\'' +
                ", psuModel='" + psuModel + '\'' +
                ", caseModel='" + caseModel + '\'' +
                ", dataStorageModel='" + dataStorageModel + '\'' +
                ", ramModel='" + ramModel + '\'' +
                ", user=" + user +
                '}';
    }
}
```

PcBuild DAO

```
package persistence;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import entity.PcBuild;

public class PcBuildDao {
    private final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(this.getClass());
    SessionFactory sessionFactory = SessionFactoryProvider.getSessionFactory();

    public PcBuild getById(int id) {
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        PcBuild pcBuild = session.get(PcBuild.class, id);
        session.close();
        return pcBuild;
    }

    public void saveOrUpdatePcBuild(PcBuild pcBuild) {
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();
        session.saveOrUpdate(pcBuild);
        transaction.commit();
        session.close();
    }

    public int insert(PcBuild pcBuild) {
        int id = 0;
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();
        id = (int) session.save(pcBuild);
        transaction.commit();
        session.close();
        return id;
    }

    public void delete(PcBuild pcBuild) {
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();
        session.delete(pcBuild);
        transaction.commit();
        session.close();
    }
}
```

The mySQL script I run before every test

```
delete from computer_builds;

delete from users;

insert into users (userId, username, password) VALUES (1, 'fchristian', 'student');

insert into users (userId, username, password) VALUES (2, 'achristian', 'lollipop');

insert into computer_builds (cpu_model, gpu_model, cpu_cooler_model, motherboard_model, psu_model, case_model,
                             data_storage_model, ram_model, userId)
values ('Ryzen 7 5800X3D', 'PowerColor Red Devil OC Radeon RX 6950 XT', 'Deepcool AK620', 'MSI MAG B550 Tomahawk',
        'Thermaltake Toughpower GF1 PE 850 W', 'Corsair 4000D Airflow ATX Mid Tower', 'Samsung 970 Evo Plus 2 TB NVMe SSD',
        'Corsair Vengeance LPX 16 GB (2 x 8 GB) DDR4-3600 CL18', 1);

insert into computer_builds (cpu_model, gpu_model, cpu_cooler_model, motherboard_model, psu_model, case_model,
                             data_storage_model, ram_model, userId)
values ('Ryzen 3 3200G', 'Gigabyte GAMING OC Radeon RX 5700 XT', 'Stock', 'Gigabyte B450M DS3H Wifi',
        'Fractal Design Ion SFX 650 W', 'Thermaltake Core G3 ATX Mid Tower', 'Teamgroup GX2 512 GB SSD',
        'Corsair Vengeance LPX 16 GB (2 x 8 GB) DDR4-3200 CL16', 2);
```

I tried testing the PcBuildDao's getById method but I keep getting a nullpointerexception.

Comment: The null pointer is coming from your test PcBuildDaoTest.getById(PcBuildDaoTest.java:24)

Comment: You have not shared the code for `PcBuildDaoTest`

Comment: Share the code of your failing test. Second your pom contains a mix of JUnit 4, Junit 5 etc. als using very old surefire/failsafe plugin version which do not even support JUnit 5 (surefire needs to be at least 2.22.2 better most recent version) also mixing vintage version/junit jupiter/engine version etc. better use the bom file of junit jupiter...and all the plugins you have defined in your pom are extremely old... use most recent versions... https://maven.apache.org/plugins